# class or static method - python

Tags: python, class, oop, static, cls

I want to understand in my case if I should use static or class method.
The idea: I'm not editing any class variable, but I'm using this variable.

example 1:

```py
class RandClass():
   static_variable = "some rand value to static variable"

   @classmethod
   def func_that_return_string_contain_static_variable(cls):
       return "some rand string" + cls.static_variable
```

example2:

```py
class RandClass():
   static_variable = "some rand value to static variable"

   @staticmethod
   def func_that_return_string_contain_static_variable():
       return "some rand string" + RandClass.static_variable
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: What is `example2`? Have you tried running that code? (btw you should be calling your variable a `class` variable)

Comment: fixed the example

Comment: What you have shown is that there are at least two ways of accessing `static_variable`. This means that you can choose which ever one suits the circumstances you are in.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: But what is *your* case? You have shown two solutions, but what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is most likely using `example1`, or an `@classmethod`.

In general, class methods are used when methods are specific to a class (and therefore use values from the class) without needing instantiation (and therefore a `self` parameter).

Static methods are generally used simply to group methods structurally - not to access attributes of the class they're in (and use them in any way).

The `cls` parameter when using an `@classmethod` will be a reference to the class it was called on, or simply `RandClass` when called as `RandClass.func_that_return_string_contain_static_variable()`. Therefore, both code blocks do the exact same thing - it's simply that using an `@classmethod` is preferred for this purpose, and using an `@staticmethod` is more of a workaround.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its a question of inheritance in subclasses. Suppose I create `class Rand2(RandClass):`. Should it be able to override the class variable? In the `classmethod` case, methods on the parent class will use the variable on the subclass (if redefined in the subclass), not the parent. This is polymorphism at work - I can change what a base method does by changing a variable on the class.

```
class RandClass():
    static_variable = "some rand value to static variable"

    @classmethod
    def func_that_return_string_contain_static_variable(cls):
        return "some rand string" + cls.static_variable


class Rand2(RandClass):
    static_variable = "and now for something completely different"

print(RandClass().func_that_return_string_contain_static_variable())
print(Rand2().func_that_return_string_contain_static_variable())
```

Outputs

```
some rand stringsome rand value to static variable
some rand stringand now for something completely different
```

In the `staticmethod` case, the parent variable is used regardless of what the subclass tries to do.

if its important that a method always use the variable defined on the base class, then use example 2. The other 99% of the time, if you use variables on the class, use a class method and access it via `cls`.